# Using a text file in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, file-io

I have a WCF service that I am writing and part of it requires reading a text file and updating the contents.

The structure of the project is:

- WCFServiceProj

  - AddressLayerFolder

    - text file
    - class with code to access file

Currently when I publish it adds a new version of the text file to the publish folder, which I can read and update, however the original file in the solution does not get updated so whenever I republish the file is out of date.

How can I get the original file updated so that publishing will not cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest answer is to not overwrite the actual file when publishing by changing its BuildAction to 'None'.  If you need the live copy of the text file then manually bring this down.

A word of caution: you shouldn't really be mixing your development and production environments in this way by having live data for development.  Of course, a slightly different approach is that if you're storing volatile data - is a text file the right mechanism to persist your data?  99 times out of a 100, it isn't.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it is not the right way to store it, was just a quick work around to get something working until we decide how to store it properly. We will more than likely go down the database route, but seeing as it is only storing a single counter for a message id we were hoping to have a brain wave at some point for an alternative solution. Having a database with a single table and column seems a bit OTT.

Comment: Just so you are aware, I ended up removing the file totally from the solution and just manually keep the file when the service is republished.